# Duplicate layer, but in different CRS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql

I inherited some data that lines up correctly on the map, but in face are in different coordinate reference systems/SRID. Here is a screenshot example:

[image]

The CRS of the green layer is:

```
EPSG: 4326
```

The CRS of the purple layer is:

```
EPSG: 2264
```

They are lined up correctly on the map, but to do stuff in PostgreSQL/PostGIS with them, they need to be in the same CRS/SRID. If I change the CRS of the green layer to match the purple layer, naturally the green layer is now way off the map.

I could manually recreate the green layer, but this would be time consuming. Is there a better solution? Could I re-create the green layer as it is, but with a different CRS? Either using some tool in QGIS or in PostgreSQL/PostGIS?

Comment: could it be that one layer is on the fly reprojected to match the other one?

Comment: Have you tried simply re-saving the green layer with QGIS in a different CRS? If they are matched on the fly then there shouldn't be a distortion after reprojection.

Comment: @DrorBogin this was the solution, so easy...  thanks!